# Yahoo Developer App (Oauth) - Can't Access Contacts Through Yahoo App?

Tags: oauth-2.0, yahoo-api

I'm integrated with the "**Yahoo Developer (Oauth)**" to allow my customers to login to their Yahoo email accounts and then be able to invite friends from their contact list.  This used to work properly but now when I try to login in, I just see a blank page from Yahoo.

https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/openid_connect/getting_started.html#getting-started-setup

I followed the above steps and have the correct **client IDs** but it's still now working properly, does anyone have experience with working with this?

I tried looking for a **Yahoo Developer** contact information or support forum but I can't seem to find any.

Thank you!

Comment: I am in this same situation now. Have you been able to find a way to get the user Yahoo Mail contact list through the oAuth2 API? I know they deprecated the Social API which is originally what everyone used.

Comment: No, unfortunately I haven't been able to get any support from Yahoo on this.  Please let me know if you make any progress on this from your end.  It's disappointing that there isn't some type of Yahoo support for any of the features that they offer.